# Module Partition for module unit was not found

Tags: c++, module

I have the following setup:

A.ixx:

```
export module A;

export import :Interface;
export import :Implementation;
```

AInterface.ixx:

```
export module A:Interface;

export class IInterface {
public:
    virtual void DoStuff() = 0;    
};
```

AImplemetation.ixx:

```
export module A:Implementation;

import :Interface;

export class Implementation : public IInterface {
public:
    void DoStuff() {
        //Do Stuff
    }
};
```

As far as i can see, this should work just fine, but i keep getting this error:

```
module partition 'Interface' for module unit 'A' was not found
```

For the AImplentation.ixx file.

Comment: copied your code to [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bnoEh9EG5), don't see any errors, can you reproduce it on godbolt and edit?

Comment: @haleyk Huh, even putting the whole of the code in there does not produce an error...  Must be some kind of configuration issue then, i am using Visual Studio 2022 and not Cmake

Answer (score -2):

Found the error, for some reason, visual studio treated the file as a C++ Header and not a C++ Compile type.